# Construct a triangle with b, c and $|\angle B - \angle C|$

Tags: geometry

How can we construct a triangle with given b, c and $|\angle B - \angle C|$?
[image]

Comment: Your figure is unclear: usually $\beta$ i the angle in $B$ and $b$ is the side opposite to $B$. Is $\bar{AB}=b$ and $\bar{AC}=c$?

Comment: So its an isoceles triangle

Comment: no. I fixed my image.

Comment: Speaking of isosceles triangles ... In the case where $|\angle B - \angle C| = 0$, then all you know is that the triangle is isosceles; whatever the (necessarily-equal) lengths $b$ and $c$ are, there are infinitely-many solutions.

Comment: Yes but if B and C are not equal then can we make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A synthetic solution:

Assume WLOG that $b > c$ then $\angle B > \angle C$. Then $|\angle B -\angle C|=\angle B -\angle C$.

Now, draw a line segment of length $b$.

Now, construct angle $\angle DAC = \angle B -\angle C$, such that $DA=c$.

Join $D$ and $C$.

Now, with $A$ as the center, draw a circle of radius $c$ and let it cut $DC$ (extended maybe) at $B$.

You have your triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call $\alpha$ the angle in $A$, $\beta$ the angle in $B$ and $\gamma$ the angle in $C$. I will discuss the case $\beta\gt\gamma$ and call $\theta=\beta-\gamma$, so that $\beta=\theta+\gamma$.

Place $A$ in the origin of a cartesian plane, and let $B$ lie on the $x$ axis, you'll have $B\equiv(b,0)$, $C\equiv(c\cos\alpha,c\sin\alpha)$ so:$$
\tan\gamma=\frac{c\sin\alpha}{b-c\cos\alpha}
$$

but we know that $\beta=\pi-\alpha-\gamma$ so $\theta+\gamma=\pi-\alpha-\gamma$ and $\alpha=\pi-\theta-2\gamma$.

Substitution for $\alpha$ gives the following equation in $\gamma$: $$
\tan\gamma=\frac{c\sin(\theta+2\gamma)}{b+c\cos(\theta+2\gamma)}
$$

Use this to find $\gamma$ so you can find the other two angles and the coordinates of $C$.

Comment: Why do we need coordinates it isnt mentioned that it has to be drawn on graph paper.

Comment: @ArchisWelankar as you cannot construct this triangle with compass and straightedge you'll need a way to place the $C$ point. Using the coordinates is just one easy way to do this task.

Comment: But we can use protractor your solution is good but why have you set limitations thats my point

Answer (score 0):

Let $B-C=x$ we know $B+C=180-A$ so we get a relation between B and A its $B=90-A/2+x/2$ so $C=90-A/2-x/2$ so now you said you know the value of $x$ ie $B-C$ so you know $A+B+C=180$ now you have all three angles in terms of A so get it. Then find the remaining side if you want use Sine rule ie $\frac{a}{sinA}=\frac{b}{sinB}=\frac{c}{sinC}$ get a ie side opposite to angle A and you can construct a triangle.